# How to promisify a regular function that I created with NodeJS Bluebird?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, bluebird

I tested Bluebird for the first time with Mongoose method calls. It was very easy, just had to do something like `Promise.promisifyAll(myObj)` and then call `myObj.methodAsync`

But when I tried to implement it without Mongoose, I didn't know what to do, for example:

```
function Foo(){}

Foo.prototype.test = function(c,cb){
  cb(new Error(),{a:1, b:2, c:c});
};

module.exports = new Foo();
```

This throws this error in `then`.

> Unhandled rejection (<{"a":1,"b":2,"c":true}>, no stack trace).

This is going to `catch`, and there I can use it without errors.

Anyone knows how to implement my method to work well with a promise implementation?

Comment: Can you show the code where you're calling `Foo.prototype.test`?

Comment: So your function always return an error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call back is returning `new Error()`, just use `cb(null, {a:1, b:2,c:c});`

Answer (score 1):

In node callbacks, the first argument to the callback is an *optional* error. If an argument is returned in the first parameter, it means the function failed. `promisify` is just wrapping your function in a promise, when your function returns, if it sees an error in the first position, it will reject the promise.

Your function is working perfectly fine as written, but its equivalent to the following in synchronous land:

`function alwaysThrows() { throw new Error() }`